# Svelte menu with Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, svelte

The menu I made in django works correctly in html. But I want to implement the same code in svelte using django rest.
How should I do this using django rest?
Of course, I prepared django rest, I just want it to work properly in svelte.

**This is my code:**

**HTML DJANGO**

```
{% load static %}
<nav class="menu__main menu__vtl">
    <ul class="menu">
        {% for html_category in html_categories %}
            {% if not html_category.parent %}
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown__link{% if request.path == html_category.get_absolute_url %} active{% endif %}">
                        {% if html_category.select_svg.title_svg %}
                            <svg class="dropdown__image"><use href="#{{ html_category.select_svg.title_svg }}"></use></svg>
                        {% endif %}
                        <span class="dropdown__text">{{ html_category.title }}</span>
                        <svg class="dropdown__arrow"><use href="#arrow-down"></use></svg>
                    </a>
                {% if html_category.subs.all %}
                    <ul class="dropdown__list">
                        {% for html_category in html_category.subs.all %}
                            {% if html_category.subs.all %}
                                <li class="sub">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub__link">
                                        <svg class="sub__arrow"><use href="#arrow-add"></use></svg>
                                        <span class="sub__text">{{ html_category.title }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="sub__list">
                                        {% for child in html_category.subs.all %}
                                            <li class="sub__list__item">
                                                <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}" class="sub__list__link{% if request.path == child.get_absolute_url %} active{% endif %}">
                                                    <span class="sub__list__text">{{ child.title }}</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                                    <a href="{{ html_category.get_absolute_url }}" class="dropdown__list__link{% if request.path == html_category.get_absolute_url %} active{% endif %}">
                                        {% if html_category.select_svg.title_svg %}
                                            <svg class="dropdown__image"><use href="#{{ html_category.select_svg.title_svg }}"></use></svg>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <span class="dropdown__list__text">{{ html_category.title }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**MENU SVELTE**

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import axios from "axios";
    let HtmlLibraryCategories = [];
    onMount(async function () {
        const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/api/library/category/'
        const response = await axios.get(endpoint);
        HtmlLibraryCategories = response.data;
      });
</script>
<nav class="menu__main menu__vtl">
    <ul class="menu">
        {#each HtmlLibraryCategories as HtmlLibraryCategory}
            {#if ! HtmlLibraryCategory.parent}
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown__link">
                        <!--{#if HtmlLibraryCategory.select_svg.title_svg }-->
                            <svg class="dropdown__image"><use href="#"></use></svg>
                        <!--{/if}-->
                        <span class="dropdown__text">{HtmlLibraryCategory.title}</span>
                        <svg class="dropdown__arrow"><use href="#arrow-down"></use></svg>
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown__list">
                    {#each HtmlLibraryCategory as HtmlLibraryCategory}
                    <li class="dropdown__list__item">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown__list__link">
                            <svg class="dropdown__image"><use href="#"></use></svg>
                            <span class="dropdown__list__text">{HtmlLibraryCategory.title}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {/each}
                </ul>
            {/if}
        {/each}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Please tell me the best solution for SVELTE?